# issue with group by in Create table as select

Tags: oracle

I have an issue very strange with my Query on Oracle. I don't have the same result for a select query if I'm creating a table from the result of this query or not.

1/ select query only :

```
SELECT PRJ_OBJECT_ID,SUBSTR(YEAR,1,4) YEAR,'ETC' UNIT,
    SUM(JAN) JAN,SUM(FEB) FEB,SUM(MAR) MAR,SUM(APR) APR,SUM(MAY) MAY,SUM(JUN) JUN,
    SUM(JUL) JUL,SUM(AUG) AUG,SUM(SEP) SEP,SUM(OCTO) OCT,SUM(NOV) NOV,SUM(DECE) DECE,sum(total) total
FROM(
    SELECT PRJ_OBJECT_ID,TO_CHAR(SLICE_DATE,'YYYYMM') YEAR,
            DECODE(TO_CHAR(SLICE_DATE,'YYYYMM'),SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(SLICE_DATE,'YYYYMM'),1,4)||TO_CHAR('01'),SUM(SLICE),0) JAN,
            DECODE(TO_CHAR(SLICE_DATE,'YYYYMM'),SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(SLICE_DATE,'YYYYMM'),1,4)||TO_CHAR('02'),SUM(SLICE),0) FEB,
            DECODE(TO_CHAR(SLICE_DATE,'YYYYMM'),SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(SLICE_DATE,'YYYYMM'),1,4)||TO_CHAR('03'),SUM(SLICE),0) MAR,
            DECODE(TO_CHAR(SLICE_DATE,'YYYYMM'),SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(SLICE_DATE,'YYYYMM'),1,4)||TO_CHAR('04'),SUM(SLICE),0) APR,
            DECODE(TO_CHAR(SLICE_DATE,'YYYYMM'),SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(SLICE_DATE,'YYYYMM'),1,4)||TO_CHAR('05'),SUM(SLICE),0) MAY,
            DECODE(TO_CHAR(SLICE_DATE,'YYYYMM'),SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(SLICE_DATE,'YYYYMM'),1,4)||TO_CHAR('06'),SUM(SLICE),0) JUN,
            DECODE(TO_CHAR(SLICE_DATE,'YYYYMM'),SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(SLICE_DATE,'YYYYMM'),1,4)||TO_CHAR('07'),SUM(SLICE),0) JUL,
            DECODE(TO_CHAR(SLICE_DATE,'YYYYMM'),SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(SLICE_DATE,'YYYYMM'),1,4)||TO_CHAR('08'),SUM(SLICE),0) AUG,
            DECODE(TO_CHAR(SLICE_DATE,'YYYYMM'),SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(SLICE_DATE,'YYYYMM'),1,4)||TO_CHAR('09'),SUM(SLICE),0) SEP,
            DECODE(TO_CHAR(SLICE_DATE,'YYYYMM'),SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(SLICE_DATE,'YYYYMM'),1,4)||TO_CHAR('10'),SUM(SLICE),0) OCTO,
            DECODE(TO_CHAR(SLICE_DATE,'YYYYMM'),SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(SLICE_DATE,'YYYYMM'),1,4)||TO_CHAR('11'),SUM(SLICE),0) NOV,
            DECODE(TO_CHAR(SLICE_DATE,'YYYYMM'),SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(SLICE_DATE,'YYYYMM'),1,4)||TO_CHAR('12'),SUM(SLICE),0) DECE,
            NVL(SUM(SLICE),0) TOTAL
        FROM PRJ_BLB_SLICES_M_ETC INNER JOIN PRASSIGNMENT PA ON PA.PRID=PRJ_OBJECT_ID
        WHERE SLICE_REQUEST_ID=113
        AND  TO_CHAR(SLICE_DATE, 'YYYY') >= TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE,-3), 'YYYY')
  and PRJ_OBJECT_ID = 5002239
    group by PRJ_OBJECT_ID,TO_CHAR(SLICE_DATE,'YYYYMM')
    )
group by PRJ_OBJECT_ID,SUBSTR(YEAR,1,4)
```

The result : I have only one line 
[image: Result]

2/ Create table from the result

```
CREATE TABLE "U_PR4_1"."MI_ETC_TEMP" as (
SELECT PRJ_OBJECT_ID,SUBSTR(YEAR,1,4) YEAR,'ETC' UNIT,
    SUM(JAN) JAN,SUM(FEB) FEB,SUM(MAR) MAR,SUM(APR) APR,SUM(MAY) MAY,SUM(JUN) JUN,
    SUM(JUL) JUL,SUM(AUG) AUG,SUM(SEP) SEP,SUM(OCTO) OCT,SUM(NOV) NOV,SUM(DECE) DECE,sum(total) total
FROM(
    SELECT PRJ_OBJECT_ID,TO_CHAR(SLICE_DATE,'YYYYMM') YEAR,
            DECODE(TO_CHAR(SLICE_DATE,'YYYYMM'),SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(SLICE_DATE,'YYYYMM'),1,4)||TO_CHAR('01'),SUM(SLICE),0) JAN,
            DECODE(TO_CHAR(SLICE_DATE,'YYYYMM'),SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(SLICE_DATE,'YYYYMM'),1,4)||TO_CHAR('02'),SUM(SLICE),0) FEB,
            DECODE(TO_CHAR(SLICE_DATE,'YYYYMM'),SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(SLICE_DATE,'YYYYMM'),1,4)||TO_CHAR('03'),SUM(SLICE),0) MAR,
            DECODE(TO_CHAR(SLICE_DATE,'YYYYMM'),SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(SLICE_DATE,'YYYYMM'),1,4)||TO_CHAR('04'),SUM(SLICE),0) APR,
            DECODE(TO_CHAR(SLICE_DATE,'YYYYMM'),SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(SLICE_DATE,'YYYYMM'),1,4)||TO_CHAR('05'),SUM(SLICE),0) MAY,
            DECODE(TO_CHAR(SLICE_DATE,'YYYYMM'),SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(SLICE_DATE,'YYYYMM'),1,4)||TO_CHAR('06'),SUM(SLICE),0) JUN,
            DECODE(TO_CHAR(SLICE_DATE,'YYYYMM'),SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(SLICE_DATE,'YYYYMM'),1,4)||TO_CHAR('07'),SUM(SLICE),0) JUL,
            DECODE(TO_CHAR(SLICE_DATE,'YYYYMM'),SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(SLICE_DATE,'YYYYMM'),1,4)||TO_CHAR('08'),SUM(SLICE),0) AUG,
            DECODE(TO_CHAR(SLICE_DATE,'YYYYMM'),SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(SLICE_DATE,'YYYYMM'),1,4)||TO_CHAR('09'),SUM(SLICE),0) SEP,
            DECODE(TO_CHAR(SLICE_DATE,'YYYYMM'),SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(SLICE_DATE,'YYYYMM'),1,4)||TO_CHAR('10'),SUM(SLICE),0) OCTO,
            DECODE(TO_CHAR(SLICE_DATE,'YYYYMM'),SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(SLICE_DATE,'YYYYMM'),1,4)||TO_CHAR('11'),SUM(SLICE),0) NOV,
            DECODE(TO_CHAR(SLICE_DATE,'YYYYMM'),SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(SLICE_DATE,'YYYYMM'),1,4)||TO_CHAR('12'),SUM(SLICE),0) DECE,
            NVL(SUM(SLICE),0) TOTAL
        FROM PRJ_BLB_SLICES_M_ETC INNER JOIN PRASSIGNMENT PA ON PA.PRID=PRJ_OBJECT_ID
        WHERE SLICE_REQUEST_ID=113
        AND  TO_CHAR(SLICE_DATE, 'YYYY') >= TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE,-3), 'YYYY')
  and PRJ_OBJECT_ID = 5002239
    group by PRJ_OBJECT_ID,TO_CHAR(SLICE_DATE,'YYYYMM')
    )
group by PRJ_OBJECT_ID,SUBSTR(YEAR,1,4))
```

Result in the table : one line by month

[image: Result table]
Thanks by advance for your help,

Comment: Which version of Oracle are you using ? Could be a bug in Oracle and you need to contact the support by [creating a service request](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/MosIndex.jspx?_afrLoop=383541911593133&_afrWindowMode=0&_adf.ctrl-state=ij0rwzu8q_4)

Comment: wrap your first query in this statement select count(1) from (your-first-query) to check that it actually return one row. maybe SQL developer shows just first row of the result

Comment: something is not right, your sql has a group by for the first two columns -- so the only way your create table as select could get multiple rows is if those two columns had different values from your inner query.  Maybe, just an idea, in your inner query rename that YEAR column to YEARMO, that is the only reason I could think why you would get 12 rows

Comment: My version of ORACLE : V12 . I have replaced YEAr by YEARMO, but same result :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

issue fixed by updating the query (solution provided in another forum) :

```
  select PR.PRJ_OBJECT_ID
   , to_char(SLICE_DATE, 'YYYY')                                         as YEAR
   , 'ETC'                                                               as UNIT
   , sum(case to_char(SLICE_DATE, 'MM') when '01' then SLICE else 0 end) as JAN
   , sum(case to_char(SLICE_DATE, 'MM') when '02' then SLICE else 0 end) as FEB
   , sum(case to_char(SLICE_DATE, 'MM') when '03' then SLICE else 0 end) as MAR
   , sum(case to_char(SLICE_DATE, 'MM') when '04' then SLICE else 0 end) as APR
   , sum(case to_char(SLICE_DATE, 'MM') when '05' then SLICE else 0 end) as MAY
   , sum(case to_char(SLICE_DATE, 'MM') when '06' then SLICE else 0 end) as JUN
   , sum(case to_char(SLICE_DATE, 'MM') when '07' then SLICE else 0 end) as JUL
   , sum(case to_char(SLICE_DATE, 'MM') when '08' then SLICE else 0 end) as AUG
   , sum(case to_char(SLICE_DATE, 'MM') when '09' then SLICE else 0 end) as SEP
   , sum(case to_char(SLICE_DATE, 'MM') when '10' then SLICE else 0 end) as OCTO
   , sum(case to_char(SLICE_DATE, 'MM') when '11' then SLICE else 0 end) as NOV
   , sum(case to_char(SLICE_DATE, 'MM') when '12' then SLICE else 0 end) as DECE
   , coalesce(sum(SLICE), 0)                                             as TOTAL
from PRJ_BLB_SLICES_M_ETC PR
join PRASSIGNMENT         PA ON PA.PRID = PR.PRJ_OBJECT_ID  where PR.SLICE_REQUEST_ID = 113
 and SLICE_DATE         >= trunc(add_months(sysdate, -3), 'yyyy')
 and PR.PRJ_OBJECT_ID    = 5002239 group by PR.PRJ_OBJECT_ID
   , to_char(SLICE_DATE, 'YYYY');
```

Issue seems be a bug in Oracle 12.